# Sylius order update concurrency issue

Tags: symfony, sylius

when under high load (doing load testing to test the checkout process) it seems our Custom Order Controller is throwing an exception when payment is being made. This happens on around 1 in 9 orders:

```
RaceConditionException: "Operated entity was previously modified."
```

We have overridden the sylius_shop_checkout_complete route as follows

```
sylius_shop_checkout_complete:
path: /complete
methods: [GET, PUT]
defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.order:completeSectionAction
    _sylius:
        event: complete
        flash: false
        template: "@SyliusShop/Checkout/complete.html.twig"
        repository:
            method: findCartForSummary
            arguments:
                - "expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart().getId()"
        state_machine:
            graph: sylius_order_checkout
            transition: complete
        redirect:
            route: sylius_shop_order_pay
            parameters:
                tokenValue: resource.tokenValue
        form:
            type: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Checkout\CompleteType
            options:
                validation_groups: 'sylius_checkout_complete'
```

and also our own check payment status route which the PaymentGateway redirects to after payment, as follows:

```
sylius_shop_checkout_status:
path: /check-status
methods: [GET, PUT]
defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.order:checkStatusAction
    _sylius:
        event: complete
        flash: false
        template: "@SyliusShop/Checkout/complete.html.twig"
        repository:
            method: findCartForSummary
            arguments:
                - "expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart().getId()"
        state_machine:
            graph: sylius_order_checkout
            transition: complete
        redirect:
            route: sylius_shop_order_pay
            parameters:
                tokenValue: resource.tokenValue
        form:
            type: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Checkout\CompleteType
            options:
                validation_groups: 'sylius_checkout_complete'
```

At the checkStatusAction function we get the following exception

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Sylius\Component\Resource\Exception\RaceConditionException: "Operated entity was previously modified." at /srv/sylius/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Doctrine/ORM/Handler/ResourceUpdateHandler.php line 46 {"exception":"[object] (Sylius\\Component\\Resource\\Exception\\RaceConditionException(code: 0): Operated entity was previously modified. at /srv/sylius/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Doctrine/ORM/Handler/ResourceUpdateHandler.php:46, Doctrine\\ORM\\OptimisticLockException(code: 0): The optimistic lock on an entity failed. at /srv/sylius/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/OptimisticLockException.php:64)"} []
```

Here is our checkStatus function:

```
public function checkStatusAction(Request $request, LoggerInterface $logger): Response
{
    $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);

    $this->isGrantedOr403($configuration, ResourceActions::UPDATE);
    $resource = $this->findOr404($configuration);

    $form = $this->resourceFormFactory->create($configuration, $resource);

    $payment = $resource->getLastPayment();
    $paymentMethod = $payment->getMethod();
    $paymentConfig = $paymentMethod->getGatewayConfig()->getConfig();
    $paymentFactoryName = $paymentMethod->getGatewayConfig()->getFactoryName();

    $response = $this->checkPaymentStatus($request->get('resourcePath'), $resource, $paymentConfig);
    $decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);

    if(substr($decodedResponse['result']['code'], 0, 4 ) === '000.') {

        // If need to run scheduler
        $tcResponse = null;
        if ($paymentFactoryName === 'tp_payment_subscription' || $paymentFactoryName === 'tp_bank_transfer') {

            $amount = $paymentFactoryName === 'tp_bank_transfer' ?  0.00 : number_format($resource->getTotal() / 100, 2, '.', '');
            $tcResponse = $this->createSubscription($resource, $response, $amount, $paymentConfig);
        }

        // Store payment details
        $paymentDetails = [
            'PayOn' => $response,
            'TotalControl' => $tcResponse
        ];
        $payment->setDetails($paymentDetails);
        $payment->setState(Payment::STATE_COMPLETED);

        try {
            $this->resourceUpdateHandler->handle($resource, $configuration, $this->manager);
        } catch (UpdateHandlingException $exception) {

            if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
                return $this->viewHandler->handle(
                    $configuration,
                    View::create($form, $exception->getApiResponseCode())
                );
            }

            $this->flashHelper->addErrorFlash($configuration, $exception->getFlash());

            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToReferer($configuration);
        }

        // if ($configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
        //     $this->flashHelper->addSuccessFlash($configuration, ResourceActions::UPDATE, $resource);
        // }

        $postEvent = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPostEvent(ResourceActions::UPDATE, $configuration, $resource);

        return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToResource($configuration, $resource);
    }

    $this->flashHelper->addErrorFlash($configuration, 'something_went_wrong_error');

    $flashes = $request->getSession()->getBag('flashes');
    $flashes->add('error', [
        'message' => 'sylius.totalp.payment_failure',
        'parameters' => ['hello' => 'hi']
    ]);

    return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToReferer($configuration, $resource);
}
```

The error is specifically happening at the following line:

```
$this->resourceUpdateHandler->handle($resource, $configuration, $this->manager);
```

This issue only happens when the website has many orders happening at the same time, does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix this, if anyone has this issue, the Sylius order number generator does not seem to be built for heavy concurrent load.

Specifically the SequentialOrderNumberGenerator.php.

We changed the following (i've left in the commented code for clarity)

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function generate(OrderInterface $order): string
{
    //$sequence = $this->getSequence();

    //$this->sequenceManager->lock($sequence, LockMode::OPTIMISTIC, $sequence->getVersion());

    $number = $this->generateNumber($order);
    //$sequence->incrementIndex();

    return $number;
}

private function generateNumber($order): string
{
    //$number = $this->startNumber + $index;

    return str_pad((string) $order->getId(), $this->numberLength, '0', \STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```